# What scope name can I use in jclouds scriptbuilder

Tags: java, openstack, jclouds

Using Jclouds script builder to run script via ssh on remote server

```
new ScriptBuilder()
  .addEnvironmentVariableScope(scope, ImmutableMap.of("KEY", "VALUE))
  .addStatement(exec(script))
  .render(OsFamily.UNIX);
```

In java docs I met

```
/**
 * Exports a variable inside the script
 * @param scopeName
 * @param variables keys are the variables to export in UPPER_UNDERSCORE case format
 */
```

the same is here: https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/javadoc/2.0.x/org/jclouds/scriptbuilder/ScriptBuilder.html

But I need to get variable `$KEY` in my script. What scope should I set?

Answer (score 1):

The `ScriptBuilder` object will export the variables in function which name is the given scope. It creates something like this:

```sh
function scopeName {
   export VAR1="value1"
   export VAR2="value2"
   return $?
}
```

That class is mostly intended to be used by the `InitScript` to generate the bootstrap script for the provisioned nodes. If this is not what you want, you can try using the `EnvBuilder` instead.

Comment: yeah, thnx. I found it in jclouds tests)